# Xcode 8 code completion: Documentation

Tags: xcode, documentation, xcode8, doxygen

I've always documented my code with doxygen `//! @brief` comments because Xcode, when autocompleting, showed the *documentation* of methods and variables.

Is this feature available as an option in Xcode 8?

Answer (score 1):

Apple seems to have dropped for support for DOxygen & HeaderDoc style document comments, for the new Swift style comments.

"@param name comment" has been replaced with "- Parameter name: comment". Same for calls to Returns, Throws & other calls. The @brief & @description has been removed completely.

Unless someone else has found a way to do this?